# New Page on Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am very new to Xamarin.

I have created a login page for my app but I need a new page to use as the main menu. The new page should be editable on Xcode to design the UI. It also needs a `ViewController.cs` to run some code inside it.

Are there any possible ways that I can create a page which needs my requirements that I have just mentioned?

Comment: What have you tried?  Just "File --> New" should present you with a dialog showing all the different options available.

Comment: @Jason I tried doing File --> New --> Storyboard but It didn't create a ViewController and it didn't show up on Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a new ViewControl in Xcode then I specified it's class at identity inspector and I also gave it a storyboard ID from the same menu.

Then I wrote the following code to display the new ViewControl.

```
        MainViewController mainViewController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MainViewController") as MainViewController;
        mainViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
        PresentViewController(mainViewController, true, null);
```

MainViewController is the class that I mentioned in identity inspector and second MainViewController which is inside the quotation mark is my storyboard ID.